# Find if Exactly One Element in An Array Is True

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Write a function `one` that accepts an array and a callback as arguments. The function should call the callback for each element of the array, passing in the element and its index. The function should return a boolean indicating whether or not exactly one element of the array results in true when passed into the callback.

This is what I've written so far:

```js
function one(array, cb) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let element = cb(array[i]);
    if (element === true) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

let result1 = one(['x', 'y', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("1 F:" + result1); // false

let result2 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("2 T:" + result2); // true

let result3 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'a', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("3 F:" + result3); // false

let result4 = one(['apple', 'dog'], function(el) {
  return el.length > 3;
});
console.log("4 T:" + result4); // true

let result5 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'pear'], function(el) {
  return el.length > 3;
});
console.log("5 F:" + result5); // false

let result6 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'food', 'cat'], function(el, idx) {
  return el.length === idx;
});
console.log("6 T:" + result6); // true
```

Comment: Do you have a specific issue with what you've written? I can see that you're not passing the index in to the callback. Also this line in the problem statement makes no sense, given that there's no outline of the logic to evaluate in the function: `The function should return a boolean indicating whether or not exactly one element of the array results in true`. I presume that should instead be 'exactly one element of the array has the provided value'

Comment: Yes, it's counting results where the callback returns as true twice as true.  It should only count it if it occurs just once.  For example, result3 should be false because the arrays contains "a" twice.

Comment: `console.log('1 F:', one(['x','y','z'], (el) =>(el === 'a'))); // false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the array by cb and check that the length is 1.

```js
function one(array, cb) {
  return array.filter(cb).length === 1;
}

let result1 = one(['x', 'y', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("1 F:" + result1); // false

let result2 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("2 T:" + result2); // true

let result3 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'a', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("3 F:" + result3); // false

let result4 = one(['apple', 'dog'], function(el) {
  return el.length > 3;
});
console.log("4 T:" + result4); // true

let result5 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'pear'], function(el) {
  return el.length > 3;
});
console.log("5 F:" + result5); // false

let result6 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'food', 'cat'], function(el, idx) {
  return el.length === idx;
});
console.log("6 T:" + result6); // true
```

Comment: this approach generates an superfluous array and needs to iterate all items.

Comment: True. but it's short and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a counter and start with `-1` and add all [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values. For the result at the end of the loop return the negated boolean value.

How does it work?

Assume, you have no item which fits, then the value is still `-1` this is truthy and negated it returns `false`.

If only one item fits the condition, it adds one to the count and now it is zero until the end of the loop. The returned value is `true`.

If more than one item matches the condition, the count is now greater than zero and the returned value is `false`.

---

Some other annotations:

- Hand over the index as well to the callback, like

  ```
  cb(array[i], i)
  ```
- Prevent a too early exit, you need to loop at least to count one.

```js
function one(array, cb) {
    let c = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        c += Boolean(cb(array[i], i));
        if (c === 1) return false; // early exit
    }
    return !c;
}

let result1 = one(['x', 'y', 'z'], function(el) { return el === 'a'; });
console.log("1 F:" + result1); // false

let result2 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'z'], function(el) { return el === 'a'; });
console.log("2 T:" + result2); // true

let result3 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'a', 'z'], function(el) { return el === 'a'; });
console.log("3 F:" + result3); // false

let result4 = one(['apple', 'dog'], function(el) { return el.length > 3; });
console.log("4 T:" + result4); // true

let result5 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'pear'], function(el) { return el.length > 3; });
console.log("5 F:" + result5); // false

let result6 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'food', 'cat'], function(el, idx) { return el.length === idx; });
console.log("6 T:" + result6); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to pass index to the callback
2. You shouldn't return if the result is true, you should count how many results are true

```js
function one(array, cb) {
  let trueCount = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const result = cb(array[i], i);
    trueCount += +result
  }
  return trueCount === 1
}

let result1 = one(['x', 'y', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("1 F:" + result1); // false

let result2 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("2 T:" + result2); // true

let result3 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'a', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("3 F:" + result3); // false

let result4 = one(['apple', 'dog'], function(el) {
  return el.length > 3;
});
console.log("4 T:" + result4); // true

let result5 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'pear'], function(el) {
  return el.length > 3;
});
console.log("5 F:" + result5); // false

let result6 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'food', 'cat'], function(el, idx) {
  return el.length === idx;
});
console.log("6 T:" + result6); // true
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did forget to pass the index!

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to return false if there are multiple matches. You can count matches until the match count is 2 and then stop. There is no need to continue iterating over the array once you have met the false condition.

```js
function one(array, predicate) {

  let foundCount = 0;

  for (let index = 0, item = array[0]; foundCount <= 1 && index <
    array.length; item = array[++index]) {
    foundCount += predicate(item, index);
  }

  // foundCount could be 0, 1 or 2
  // return true if foundCount is 1
  return foundCount === 1;
}


let result1 = one(['x', 'y', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("1 F:" + result1); // false

let result2 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("2 T:" + result2); // true

let result3 = one(['x', 'a', 'y', 'a', 'z'], function(el) {
  return el === 'a';
});
console.log("3 F:" + result3); // false

let result4 = one(['apple', 'dog'], function(el) {
  return el.length > 3;
});
console.log("4 T:" + result4); // true

let result5 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'pear'], function(el) {
  return el.length > 3;
});
console.log("5 F:" + result5); // false

let result6 = one(['apple', 'dog', 'food', 'cat'], function(el, idx) {
  return el.length === idx;
});
console.log("6 T:" + result6); // true
```